# Play Blu-rays using Media Player Classic, I have PowerDVD10

Tags: windows-7, blu-ray, media-player-classic, powerdvd

So my laptop came with a copy of PowerDVD10 but I would prefer to use Media Player Classic (v1.5.3.3819). I had read somewhere you can make it use PowerDVDs codecs but I have no idea how to set this up. If it helps I'm on Windows 7 64-bit and I installed MPC through the latest Combined Community Codec Pack which is all 32-bit it seems.

Comment: `I had read somewhere` Where?

Answer (score 5):

I personally prefer the [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm) over the Combined Community Codec Pack, as being much more evolved.

K-Lite also has as a separate download the [K-Lite Codec Pack 64-bit](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K-Lite_Codec_Pack_64-bit.htm): A bundle of 64-bit DirectShow filters that can be used together with 64-bit players, such as Windows Media Center.

[EDIT]

Please note that some blu-ray copy-protections work better with Windows Media Player
or with the software that was furnished with the disc.

Some more advice found in [How to play Blu-Ray discs with Media Player Classic](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/play-blu-ray-discs-media-player-classic-t4991.html?s=db4a292d101b1aac803100dc032caed0&) :

**How to set up Media Player Classic to play Blu-Ray discs**

Select `View -> Options -> External filters`

- Add filter "Haali Media Splitter (AR)", Set merit 00900000, Set Prefer
- Add Filter "ffdshow audio decoder", Set merit 00700000
- Add filter "cyberlink H.264/AVC Decoder", Set merit 00900400
- Add Filter "Sonic Cinemaster Audio Decoder 4.3.0", Set merit 00805000
- Add Filter "ffdshow video decoder", Set merit 00800000 (late fix to stop ffdshow taking over from cyberlink)
- Add Filter "Sonic Cinemaster Video Decoder", Set merit 00700000 (late fix to stop Cinemaster Video taking over from ffdshow video)
- Add Filter "Cyberlink Video/SP Decoder (pdvd7), set merit "prefer" (Try this for some hardware acceleration in Windows XP)
- Add Filter "Nvidia Video Decoder", Set merit "Prefer" (block cyberlink) (try this for hardware acceleration in Windows XP/Vista if you have Nvidia Purevideo)

These codecs and splitters should already be installed by your codec pack. If not, use another codec pack.

Select `View -> Options -> Internal filters`

- Deselect any mpeg, matroska from the source list
- Deselect any AC3, mpeg from the transport filter list

Comment: How is this an answer? I;m asking about using the codecs for Blu ray playback from PowerDVD in Media Player Classic. There is no legal free codecs for Blu ray playback.

Comment: Playback problems are many times caused by lack of codec. Codecs are system-wide and not specific to a single program. I don't know if Media Player Classic is 64-bit, which you can verify in Task Manager : if 32-bit then it will have `*32` after the process-name. If it is 64-bit, you could try installing K-Lite Codec Pack 64-bit. I really recommend uninstalling Community Pack and installing K-Lite, because its installation checks for many problems and it installs Media Player Classic which should work with the codecs it installs. (Verify which version of K-Lite contains Media Player Classic.)

Comment: I have added some more info that might be helpful. The codecs mentioned above come from your system. They might have been installed by the installation of PowerDVD10, but also by your installing a codec pack.

Comment: I had tried this article but got stopped at 3 since that codec was not.on the list though many other cyberlink stuff was there. Also there's no obvious way to set prefer.

Comment: Cyberlink H.264 is included in K-Lite. Sonic Cinemaster is not as it seems to have become part of a commercial product, but you could try doing without it. Prefer is a radio-button on the right side in the External filters dialog. Better use one of the higher versions of K-Lite.

Comment: Is the internal filters section codecs built into Media Player Classic? I just installed the 64-bit version and K-lite 64 after removing CCCP.

Comment: Also I can't find Cyberlink H.264 on the list for External filters now...K-lite 64 is installed.

Comment: Conjecture: The codec may not be available in 64-bit. Use in this case the 32-bits player version - it should work equally as well as the 64-bit one.

Comment: It would appear that Cyberlink is no longer included w/ K-Lite? (9.5.0)